# How can I bump a version number using bash

Tags: bash, replace

I would like to know how to bump the last digit in a version number using bash.

e.g.

```
VERSION=1.9.0.9
NEXT_VERSION=1.9.0.10
```

EDIT: The version number will only contain natural numbers.

Can the solution be generic to handle any number of parts in a version number.

e.g.

```
1.2
1.2.3
1.2.3.4
1.2.3.4.5
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

**TL;DR:**

```
VERSION=1.9.0.9
echo $VERSION | awk -F. '/[0-9]+\./{$NF++;print}' OFS=.
# will print 1.9.0.10
```

For a detailed explanation, read on.

---

Let's start with the basic [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4485581/15168) by [froogz3301](https://stackoverflow.com/users/83416/froogz3301):

```
VERSIONS="
1.2.3.4.4
1.2.3.4.5.6.7.7
1.9.9
1.9.0.9
"

for VERSION in $VERSIONS; do 
    echo $VERSION | awk -F. '{$NF = $NF + 1;} 1' | sed 's/ /./g'
done
```

How can we improve on this?  Here are a bunch of ideas extracted from the copious set of comments.

The trailing '1' in the program is crucial to its operation, but it is not the most explicit way of doing things. The odd '1' at the end is a boolean value that is true, and therefore matches every line and triggers the default action (since there is no action inside braces after it) which is to print $0, the line read, as amended by the previous command.

Hence, why not this `awk` command, which obviates the `sed` command?

```
awk -F. '{$NF+=1; OFS="."; print $0}'
```

Of course, we could refine things further — in several stages. You could use the bash '<<<' string redirection operator to avoid the pipe:

```
awk -F. '...' <<< $VERSION
```

The next observation would be that given a series of lines, a single execution of awk could handle them all:

```
echo "$VERSIONS" | awk -F. '/[0-9]+\./{$NF+=1;OFS=".";print}'
```

without the for loop.  The double quotes around "$VERSION" preserve the newlines in the string.  The pipe is still unnecessary, leading to:

```
awk -F. '/[0-9]+\./{$NF+=1;OFS=".";print}' <<< "$VERSIONS"
```

The regex ignores the blank lines in `$VERSION` by only processing lines that contain a digit followed by a dot.  Of course, setting OFS in each line is a tad clumsy, and '`+=1`' can be abbreviated '`++`', so you could use:

```
awk -F. '/[0-9]+\./{$NF++;print}' OFS=. <<< "$VERSIONS"
```

(or you could include '`BEGIN{OFS="."}`' in the program, but that is rather verbose.

The '`<<<`' notation is only supported by Bash and not by Korn, Bourne or other POSIX shells (except as a non-standard extension parallelling the Bash notation).  The AWK program is going to be supported by any version of `awk` you are likely to be able to lay hands on (but the variable assignment on the command line was not supported by old UNIX 7th Edition AWK).

Comment: Thanks, I'm using:

```
## bump-%: bump the % chart version number
bump-%: docs lint update-deps
 @echo "$$(awk -F. '{if ($$0 ~ /version: [0-9]+\./) {$$NF++;print} else {print}}' OFS=. $(CHARTS_FOLDER)/$*/Chart.yaml)" > $(CHARTS_FOLDER)/$*/Chart.yaml
```
in a Makefile to bump chart versions.

Answer (score 10):

I have come up with this.

```
VERSIONS="
1.2.3.4.4
1.2.3.4.5.6.7.7
1.9.9
1.9.0.9
"

for VERSION in $VERSIONS; do 
    echo $VERSION | awk -F. '{$NF = $NF + 1;} 1' | sed 's/ /./g'
done
```

Comment: Thank you for the more elegant solution

Comment: Of course, we could refine things further - in a couple of stages.  One would use the bash '`<<<`' string redirection operator to avoid the pipe: `awk -F. '...' <<< $VERSION`.  The next observation would be that given a series of lines, a single execution of `awk` could handle them all: `echo "$VERSIONS" | awk -F. '/[0-9]+\./{$NF+=1;OFS=".";print}'` without the for loop; the double quotes around `"$VERSION"` preserve the newlines in the string, and then the pipe is still unnecessary, leading to: `awk -F. '/[0-9]+\./{$NF+=1;OFS=".";print}' <<< "$VERSIONS"`.  The regex ignores the blank lines.

Comment: Of course, setting OFS in each line is a tad clumsy, and '+=1' can be abbreviated '++', so you could use: `awk -F. '/[0-9]+\./{$NF++;print}' OFS=. <<< "$VERSIONS"` (or you could include '`BEGIN{OFS="."}`' in the program, but that is rather verbose.

Comment: @Jonathan: The trailing 1 is a boolean that forces the default action which is `print`. It's different from a leading 1 which selects only the first line of input. For incrementing, `$NF++` also works. You only need to set the output delimiter once. Result: `awk -F. '{$NF++}1' OFS=.` or `awk -F. '1{$NF++}1' OFS=.`. I prefer an explicit print instead of the implicit one, though, but the `$0` isn't necessary: `awk -F. '{$NF++; print}' OFS=.`. The `OFS` could also be set using a `-v` argument or in a `BEGIN` clause. I see you said several of the things I was in the process of typing up.

Comment: @Dennis: OK - yup; the leading 1 is either redundant or incorrect, depending on the desired result. If redundant, all lines are processed just as they are with it present; if incorrect, the correct condition is probably '`NR==1`'. The trailing 1 is not redundant; it triggers the printing when there isn't an explicit print operation. I prefer the explicit print operations by far (especially to the trailing 1); it took me a few seconds to see what it was doing (more or less) when I first looked; and I partially misinterpreted it - more evidence of it not being a particularly good abbreviation!

Comment: @Jonathan: Anything that's true will work. Perhaps a better abbreviation would be `awk -F. '{$NF++}"print"' OFS=.` ... oh, wait... ;)

Comment: @Dennis: maybe we should set up a community wiki expanded answer with this commentary?

Answer (score 3):

```
if [[ "$VERSION" == *.* ]]; then
    majorpart="${VERSION%.*}."
else
    majorpart=""
fi
minorpart="${VERSION##*.}"
NEXT_VERSION="$majorpart$((minorpart+1))"
```

Warning: if the minor part of the version number isn't in the expected format (integer, no leading zeros), this may have trouble.  Some examples: "1.033" -> "1.28" (since 033 is octal for 27), "1.2.b" -> "1.2.1" (unless b is a defined variable, it'll be treated as 0), "1.2.3a" -> error ("3a" isn't a number).  Depending on how many cases you want to cover, this can be made arbitrarily complex.

Comment: You can force a number such as "033" to be interpreted as decimal like so: `NEXT_VERSION="$majorpart$((10#$minorpart+1))"` and "033" will become "34". It's a good idea to do this since "038" will produce and error. However, it will cause your "b" example to produce an error.

Answer (score 2):

Well, [Jonathan Leffler](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15168) already [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4486087/1608594) the question, however I've generalized the solution to accept an arbitrary diff (passed as an awk parameter `versionDiff`):

```sh
VERSION="1.4.1.2"
awk -v versionDiff="0.1" -F. -f bump.awk OFS=. <<< "$VERSION"
```

the result will be:

```
1.5.0.0
```

as the numbers after last non-zero versionDiff number are zeroed.

and the `bump.awk`:

```
/[0-9]+\./ {
  n = split(versionDiff, versions, ".")
  if(n>NF) nIter=n; else nIter=NF
  lastNonzero = nIter
  for(i = 1; i <= nIter; ++i) {
    if(int(versions[i]) > 0) {
      lastNonzero = i
    }
    $i = versions[i] + $i
  }
  for(i = lastNonzero+1; i <= nIter; ++i) {
    $i = 0
  }
  print
}
```